# What administration utilities does Ubuntu and Debian package with PostgreSQL?

Tags: postgresql, ubuntu, debian

I see that there are a lot of tools authored by Ubuntu and Debian for PostgreSQL? Does any one have a list of them, or the build-differences?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the Ubuntu-specific management utilities,

```
pg_archivecleanup
pg_basebackup
pg_config
pg_conftool
pg_createcluster
pg_ctlcluster
pg_dropcluster
pg_dump
pg_dumpall
pg_isready
pg_lsclusters
pg_receivexlog
pg_recvlogical
pg_renamecluster
pg_restore
pg_upgradecluster
pg_virtualenv
```

There are some other subtle differences with the variants provided upstream. Because Ubuntu is capable of running multiple PostgreSQL's of different versions, it distributes but disables some of their utilities ([like `pg_ctl` as addressed in this question](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/156722/2639)). In place of those utilities, it simplifies use with `service [start|stop|restart|reload] postgresql` and `pg_ctlcluster`.

Answer (score 0):

I think what gets mostly added is in the [postgresql-common](https://packages.debian.org/stretch/postgresql-common) package. As can be seen in the package page, it seems to provide us the following utilities: pg_conftool, pg_createcluster, pg_ctlcluster, pg_dropcluster, pg_lsclusters, pg_renamecluster, pg_upgradecluster, pg_virtualenv.

If you have a look at the [package itself](http://http.debian.net/debian/pool/main/p/postgresql-common/postgresql-common_181.tar.xz) in Debian, one can find:

- pg_buildext
- pg_checksystem
- pg_config
- pg_conftool
- pg_createcluster
- pg_ctlcluster
- pg_dropcluster
- pg_lsclusters
- pg_renamecluster
- pg_updatedicts
- pg_upgradecluster
- pg_virtualenv
- pg_wrapper

You could also edit some of the files this package provides if want different parameters than what the Debian maintainers chose, for example like enabling [data checksum](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/171258/how-to-install-postgresql-on-ubuntu-from-ppa-with-data-checksums-enabled) by default.